What are the parameters and requirement analysis
I am working on a project where I need to develop and implement advanced signal processing techniques. What are the parameters that I need to look into to choose the best method that gives real-time outputs.

Welcome to our SE. Your question is extremely broad and unanswerable as is. Please consider adding A LOT more detail: what is your specific application, what are you trying to do, how good does it need to be and how do you define "goodness" in your context.
